# Perl regex extracting for charcters like @ or $

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a perl script which greps few substring from the file. File contains words like `Lives@124.23`. What I need to do is to extract the numerics after the character `@`, which is `124.23` in the above case.

I tried using `/\@([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)/` pattern though pattern doesn't match with the supplied word. 
Can someone tell me how to extract this numeric?

Comment: Regex is ok, check your string prior to matching. `perl -e 'print "Lives\@124.23" =~ /\@([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)/'`

Comment: But I can see your regex is working. http://rubular.com/r/D1nJHZm96l

Comment: and you need to print the group index 1.

Comment: @mpapec : You have changed the input as you have added one character "\" with @. Without "/", regex supplied will not work. Please check again.

Comment: @Samiron yes I could see it's working but I am not sure how...as this fails on my system. BTW I am using perl, v5.10.0.

Comment: The reason for backslash above is that `@` in perl interpolates inside double quotes. In your case however data is stored in text file, so nothing gets interpolated. Btw, `perl -e 'print pop =~ /\@([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)/' Lives@124.23`

Comment: Can you please share your full code, just wondering if you are stuck with multiline regex problem.

Comment: Thanks @mpapec. My bad. Dint focus on the string and file input.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=@)\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Try this.This should work.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uV3aL0/31

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
my $string = "Lives\@124.23.2";
my (@values) = $string=~m/\@(\d+[\.\d]*)/g;
print @values;
```

Thanks.